# Error message Cannot open include file: 'gxall.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, grid, objective-grid

I am trying to build some old Visual C++ code. When i do, I get this error message:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gxall.h': No such file or directory
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is the main header file for Objective Grid, a commercial MFC grid control. It used to be sold by a company called Stingray, but now seems to be owned by RogueWave. If your company has been able to build the code before you ought to have an Objective Grid install floating round somewhere. If not you'll have to buy it.

Comment: Oh.. i didnt know that.. Thanx for that, Yeah i have got the release built binary, but in my system its not building.. any way ill check.. Thanks lot

Answer (score 0):

searching around gives this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/51b77f9b-d82b-4357-9750-773642b27ab7

Comment: I tried this, they are telling add a macro _GXDLL and include "
#include "grid\gxall.h".. but file itself is missing.. where do i get gxall library?