# Receiving "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gxall.h': No such file or directory"

Tags: visual-c++, objective-grid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error message Cannot open include file: ‘gxall.h’: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335052/error-message-cannot-open-include-file-gxall-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Hi I am working on VC++ 6.0, I have included gxall.h in stdafx.h file but while building code I am getting error :

`fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gxall.h': No such file or directory`

```
// Objective Grid
#include <gxall.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the path to Objective Grid includes folder in your project properties.

Select menu `Project->[YourProjectName] Properties` then edit `C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories` line adding your path there, e.g. `\3rdParty\OGrid12.0.2\Include`.